# DateToStr and Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I upgraded one project from XE to XE2 and I noticed that `DateToStr` doesn't work exactly as before.

If I try to covert a null date to str it gives "Invalid floating point operation". While this was not there in XE.

Why there is this difference? Are there similar behaviours for other functions? (I mean some function that in a similar case = converting a null value changes the behaviour)

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255337/delphi-xe2-formatdatetime-passing-693594

Comment: Can you show some code? Passing an uninitialized TDateTime just returns 30/12/1899 on my machine.

Comment: @pritaeas You mean passing a `TDateTime` that has value of `0.0`.

Comment: Yes, is that not what he's referring to ?

Comment: @pritaeas Probably not because a value of `0.0` does not throw an FP error

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes it is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255337/delphi-xe2-formatdatetime-passing-693594 does anyone know if this has been solved in Update 4?

Comment: I believe that this change is not going to be solved. This change is by design.

Comment: So all the third party components should adapt to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating I realized that this design choice made by Embarcadero in XE2 will affect a lot of old code. Wherever possible I replaced `DateTimeToStr` or I added checks for `NULL` dates before trying to convert to string.

Also DevExpress have some problems with their components because of this issue.